# LocalTime from Date

Tags: java, date, localtime

I'm trying to convert a `Date` instance to a `LocalTime` instance.

```
// Create the Date
Date date = format.parse("2011-02-18 05:00:00.0");    

// Convert to Calendar
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);

// Convert Calendar to LocalTime
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(cal.getTimeInMillis());
LocalTime convert = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime();
```

I don't get a compiler error but the `LocalTime` instance values are wrong.

I think it does not work because `Date` stores time in `fasttime` instead of `cdate`.

I'm using JDK version 1.8.

Comment: First is first, what version of Java are we talking about?

Comment: @RafaelR.S.Robles JDK 1.8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your input is effectively a `LocalDateTime`. It would be much simpler to simply parse that to a `LocalDateTime` and then get the `LocalTime` from that. No time zones to worry about, no somewhat-legacy classes (avoid `Date` and `Calendar` where possible...)

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S", Locale.US);

        String text = "2011-02-18 05:00:00.0";
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
        LocalTime localTime = localDateTime.toLocalTime();
        System.out.println(localTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted answer is correct but I had to still muck with it to get what I want.  To get LocalDateTime formatted to whatever you want: 

```LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"))```

Answer (score 23):

This is also quite simple:

```
LocalTime time = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(new Date().toInstant(),
    ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime();
```

Comment: can be simplified with LocalTime.ofInstant()

Comment: very bad anwser, create a localdatetime then convert to localtime? why not just create a localtime

Comment: @RafaelLima - [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76713736/10819573) is a demo of exactly what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29927527/642706) is correct. This Answer expands on those ideas.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Some of the other Answers, and the Question, mix the old legacy date-time classes with the new. That is unnecessary and bad practice. The whole point of the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes is to *replace* the troublesome and confusing old classes.

- You do *not* need `java.util.Date`.
- You do *not* need `java.util.Calendar`.

## `LocalDateTime`

Your input string lacks any information about offset-from-UTC or time zone. So we parse it as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object.

To parse, we replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for date-time formats.

```
String input = "2011-02-18 05:00:00.0".replace( " " , "T" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
```

## `LocalTime`

To focus on the time-of-day without the date, ask for a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html).

```
LocalTime lt = ldt.toLocalTime();
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Note that none of this are actual moments, not a point on the timeline. Without the context of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone, we do not know if you meant 5 AM in Auckland NZ or 5 AM in Kolkata IN or 5 AM in Paris France or 5 AM in Montréal Québec. Each of those would be very different moments in time.

If by context you do know for certain the intended time zone, apply it. Apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
```

From there, ask for the `LocalTime` if desired.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime();
```

## `Instant`

If you want to see that same moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), extract an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Generally best to focus on [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) in much of your business logic, logging, data storage, and data exchange. Learn to think of UTC as “The One True Time”.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();  // Same moment, shifted to UTC.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String datestring = "2011-02-18 05:00:00.0";
    SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");//take a look at MM
    Date date = dt.parse(datestring );
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime());
    LocalTime res = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime();
```

Comment: Silly to mix the troublesome old classes with the java.time classes. The old classes are now supplanted by java.time classes. No need for old ones.

Comment: If you have to use the old classes with the new then what do you do? Refactor whatever codebase you have to suit the new classes? That makes no sense. Sometimes there's a need to keep using the old style together with the new, and this applies to any development work, not just Java.

Answer (score 0):

### You can parse your date-time string into a `LocalTime` directly

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API<sup>*</sup>:**

Having formatted the given date-time string into [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, you can parse it to `LocalTime` directly using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`.

Alternatively, you can use the pattern `u-M-d H:m:s.S` with `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the given date-time string directly into `LocalTime`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("2011-02-18 05:00:00.0".replace(' ', 'T'), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
        System.out.println(time);

        // Alternatively,
        time = LocalTime.parse("2011-02-18 05:00:00.0", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s.S", Locale.ENGLISH));
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
05:00
05:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/wPE3ub)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).</sup>