# JTable define an editor for LocalTime type

Tags: java, swing

I am using Java 8, after following documentation:

- [How to Use Tables - Using an Editor to Validate User-Entered Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext)

I'd like to setup a specialized formatter when editing a column in my [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html). This column contains [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) instances.

```
JTable table;
...
table.setDefaultEditor(LocalTime.class, new LocalTimeEditor());
```

Where `LocalTimeEditor` is defined by (tentatively):

```
public class LocalTimeEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    JFormattedTextField ftf;

  public LocalTimeEditor() {
    super(new JFormattedTextField());
    ftf = (JFormattedTextField) getComponent();

    // Set up the editor for the LocalTime cells.
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    ftf.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(dateFormatter));
```

But this leads to the following compilation error:

```
The constructor DefaultFormatterFactory(DateTimeFormatter) is undefined
```

I'd like to stay away from a solution involving `SimpleDateFormat` (+`DateFormatter`) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29927527/136285) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44701684/136285), since [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) should be considered legacy (see old code [here](https://coderanch.com/t/338616/java/JFormattedTextField-Date)).

Is there a solution to integrate [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with [`JFormattedTextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html), or am I blocked by:

- [JDK-8034818 - JFormattedTextField does not accept DateTimeFormatter as formatter](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8034818)

I'd also like to stay away from [MaskFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html), since it does not allow easy error handling for something like: `"25:70:90"`.

Comment: Do you need to extend [JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter.html) ? Then  you would just need to implement the two abstract methods?

Comment: Following the JDK javadoc hierarchy pretty clearly shows that, with all the constraints you've stated, there's no solution within the JDK. Your only option is to implement your own as @matt said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the argument of DefaultFormatterFactor, I created a new `JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter`

```
class JTFormater extends JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter{
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter;
    public JTFormater(DateTimeFormatter formatter){
        this.formatter =  formatter;
    }
    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
        return formatter.parse(text);
    }

    @Override
    public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
        if(value instanceof TemporalAccessor){
            return formatter.format((TemporalAccessor) value);
        } else{
            throw new ParseException("not a valid type at", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

From this I could parse and display LocalTime's, although in my implementation it is pretty clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LGoodDatePicker's TimeTableEditor: https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker/blob/master/Project/src/main/java/com/github/lgooddatepicker/tableeditors/TimeTableEditor.java